# Ionic 4 Form Group with Chips

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, data-binding, directive

I have a ionic app, that should have a view showing a list of chips. There should be a possibility to add chips and to delete them. Therefore I thought of doing it with a 2-way binding on the list and a form group. that gives me the error. As I'm pretty new to ionic, I am also open to other techniques of implementing the idea.

> uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with
>   name: exampleChips

example.page.ts

```
<ion-card class="form-group">
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-list >
          <ion-chip class="form-control" name="exampleChips" id="exampleChips" [(ngModel)]="exampleModel.exampleChips" *ngFor="let example of exampleModel.exampleChips">
            <ion-label>{{example}}</ion-label>
          </ion-chip>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove your ngModel here. we don't need it.

```
<ion-card class="form-group">
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-list >
      <ion-chip class="form-control" name="exampleChips" id="exampleChips" *ngFor="let example of exampleModel.exampleChips">
        <ion-label>{{example}}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```